# Salvar requisição Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, docker

Sou iniciante em Spring Boot e preciso de uma ajudinha.
Quero salvar uma requisição de entrada e saída, gerando o id automatico e salvando também a data e hora, usando o docker e Postgres (não sei se muda algo dizer também que estou usando o maven. Perdoem ainda minha falta de conhecimento, estou aprendendo kkkk).
Com esse código, a aplicação startou, mas não funcionou pra isso que eu quero.
Podem por favor me ajudar?

Sei que podem ter algumas coisas sem lógica, mas é pelas tentativas que fui fazendo tentando ajuda pela internet.
Desde já agradeço muitíssimo! 
Quero começar a entender melhor!

ID - Gerar automaticamente e salvar no banco de dados
DATA E HORA - salvar a data e hora atual
E SE É UMA REQUISIÇÃO DE ENTRADA OU DE SAÍDA: json

Filename eu queria aplicar o pathvariable, já que posso ter vários nomes de arquivos, só que nessa situação, também não sei como implementar.

Méu código:

Application

```
package requisc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

ApplicationController

```
package requisc;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;


@RestController
public class ApplicationController {


@Autowired
RequisicaoRepository requisicaoRepository;

@RequestMapping (path="/process" + "/{filename}/" + "entry")
public Requisicao getEntry(@RequestBody @Valid Requisicao requisicao) {
    return requisicaoRepository.save(requisicao);
    }
@RequestMapping (path="/process" + "/{filename}/" + "exit")
public Requisicao getExit(@RequestBody @Valid Requisicao requisicao) {
    return requisicaoRepository.save(requisicao);
    }


}
```

Requisicao

```
package requisc;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Calendar;


@Entity
public class Requisicao{



@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="data_requisicao")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar dataRequisicao;

@Column(name="requisicao")
private String requisicao;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getRequisicao() {
    return requisicao;
}
public void setRequisicao(Requisicao <S, O> requisicao) {
    this.requisicao = String.valueOf(requisicao);
}

public Calendar getdataRequisicao() {
    return dataRequisicao;
}

public void setdataRequisicao(Calendar dataRequisicao) {
    this.dataRequisicao = dataRequisicao;
    }
}
```

RequisicaoRepository

```
package requisc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface RequisicaoRepository extends JpaRepository<Requisicao,         String> {

}
```

application-local.yml

```
db.name: integracaodb


spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/integracaodb
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a inserção de Logs para registros de requests seja o modelo mais adotado e adequado para essa situação, no entanto, se ainda sim optar por persistir todos os requests da sua aplicação, você pode criar um interceptador de requisições. Assim todas as requisições irão passar pela classe interceptadora e você pode salvar a informação na sua base de dados.

1. Para inserção de [logs](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-slf4j-logging-example/)

2.1. Para criar o interceptador, primeiro você cria uma classe para registrar seu(s) interceptador(es).

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class InterceptorRegister extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Interceptor());
    }
}
```

2.2. Depois cria a classe interceptadora

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class Interceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RequisicaoRepository requisicaoRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        Requisicao requisicao = new Requisicao();
        requisicao.setRequisicao(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        requisicao.setDataRequisicao(Calendar.getInstance());
        requisicaoRepository.save(requisicao);
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        Requisicao requisicao = new Requisicao();
        requisicao.setRequisicao(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        requisicao.setDataRequisicao(Calendar.getInstance());
        requisicaoRepository.save(requisicao);
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```